# swift 3 - Como fechar pagina aberta em uma webview?

Tags: webview, swift-3, safari

em uma, index.html viewcontroller estou usando este código para abri um arquivo html local

`self.webView = WKWebView(frame: webFrame, configuration: config)
self.webView?.uiDelegate = self as? WKUIDelegate
self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self
self.webView?.scrollView.bounces = false
self.container!.addSubview(webView!)
let testUrl: URL! = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "assets")
self.webView!.loadFileURL(testUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: testUrl)`

debugando pelo safari no menu Developer > Simulator aparece a pagina aberta
(index.html)
Acontece que toda vez que saio desta viewControler e retorno é adicionado no menu Developer > Simulator uma nova pagina (index.html, index.html,...). acredito que sejam novas página abertas em novas abas

na função que uso para sair desta viewController uso este código

`self.webView?.removeFromSuperview()
self.container.removeFromSuperview()`

os objetos são removidos porem as paginas não são, alguém sabe como remove-las?